# Does pointwise equicontinuous and uniformly equicontinuous implies compactness?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, equicontinuity

If every sequence of pointwise equicontinuous functions $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly equicontinuous, does this imply that $M$ is compact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the subspace $M=\mathbb{Z}$ of the reals, an infinite discrete space, certainly not compact. But every sequence of functions is uniformly equicontinuos in that space.